# How to access the RequestBody in a Spring WebFlux @ExceptionHandler?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

Is there a way to get access to the `RequestBody` (preferably in it's mapped form) in an `@ExceptionHandler` method using Spring WebFlux, with the default Reactor Netty?

Consider the following example:

```
@RestController
class TestRestController {

  @PostMapping("/test")
  Mono<TestBody> testPost(@RequestBody TestBody testBody) {
    return Mono.error(new NullPointerException());
  }

  @ExceptionHandler(NullPointerException.class)
  @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
  Mono<Void> handleNullPointerException(ServerWebExchange serverWebExchange) {
    return Mono.empty();
  }

}
```

At runtime additional instances of [certain types](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-ann-arguments) can be injected into the `@ExceptionHandler`'s method signature, as shown in the above example with `ServerWebExchange`. But the docs clearly state that it doesn't support request body arguments (see the note in [this section](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-ann-controller-exceptions)).

Using the Servlet stack, you can inject the `RequestContext` as [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46046430/1930325). Is there an equivalent or similar approach for the WebFlux stack?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get request values from ExceptionHandler using Spring MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52523173/get-request-values-from-exceptionhandler-using-spring-mvc)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way, but not a really good looking one. We had kind of the same problem, but in our case we've wanted to have access on the reactive context, since we've stubbornly chose to use the MDC in this reactive paradigm, so the MDC rely on that context.

After lots of back-and-forth with the Exception handlers and controller advice, it was pretty obvious that the reactive context could not be accessed there.

So we've extends the **AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler** . Here there is a **handle(ServerWebExchange exchange, Throwable throwable)** method that will be called when you're application has an error. The good part is that there is the **ServerWebExchange** and you can access the context like: **exchange.getAttributes().get(MDC_CONTEXT)** or the body like: **exchange.getRequest().getBody()**.

So that resolved our MDC problem, but the mapping of the errors had to be handled manually unfortunately. I've remember that we've invested a lot of time, and at that time, that was the best solution. Cheers!

Comment: I thought if you return Mono/Flux from the exception handler, then you have access to the Reactor context.

Comment: In our case, we needed access to the context exactly in the ExceptionHandler methods, in order to take the MDC and log the error messages with a correlationID that belongs to a specific request.

Comment: This doesn't work. request body comes as empty.

Comment: @ChandreshMishra it is sad to see that this framework is out since last 5-6 years, yet there are no recommended, proper solution to these basic problems like request/response Logging, beanValidation. Buffering the req/res in webFilter only works for happy path. any exception thrown in Filter doesn't invoke the req/res decorators, hence we are bound to handle req/res logging from errorHandler in reactive.