# Around Advice not working when dependent on response from other REST service

Tags: spring-mvc, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

I am working with Spring AOP to define a common fallback method instead of duplicating code.
I used @Around as I have to return the object from Aspect.I am trying to decide @Around advice depending on the response returned,but not able to do so.
Here is my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add/employee", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public EmployeeResponse addEmployee(@RequestParam("name") String name, @RequestParam("empId") String empId) {
        EmployeeResponse employeeResponse=employeeService.createEmployee(name, empId);
        return employeeResponse;

    }
```

createEmployee in the service class is used to call another endpoint to insert some data.I want to decide my advice based on the employeeResponse but not able to do so.
I tried @AfterReturning also,but I can't return the object if I use that.

Below is my aspect class:

```
@Around(value = "execution(* com.test.service.EmployeeService.*(..)) and args(name,empId)")
public Object getAllAdvice2(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, String name,String empId) throws Throwable {
    System.out.println("Inside Aspect");
     Object[] arguments = pjp.getArgs();
    if (!checkForPath()) {
        return pjp.proceed();
    }
    System.out.println("Call Second path please!!");
    return arguments;
    }

    private boolean checkForPath() {
        HttpServletResponse response = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes())
        .getResponse();
        return response.getStatus()==501?true:false;
    }
}
```

I did use HttpServletResponse and RequestContextHolder to get the context but seems it will take the present context i.e. "/add/employee".
How can I return the actual status from the checkForPath () (since I don't need to call pjp.proceed for every status code returned) so that I can execute the line System.out.println("Call Second path please!!"); depending on my error code.

Can anyone pls suggest where it is going wrong?

Comment: `HttpServletResponse` becomes relevant when the code returns from `addEmployee()`.Before calling the `employeeService.createEmployee(name, empId)` checking the response status makes no sense , if that is what you are trying to do.

Comment: Yeah...makes sense...so can you pls suggest how to check the status after being the response returned from employeeService.createEmployee Or how can I add  HttpServletResponse in  createEmployee() using AOP around advice

Comment: You could throw an exception from `createEmployee()` based on whatever condition you want to check and use a [`ControllerAdvice`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ControllerAdvice.html) to handle the response . Example [here](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc)

Comment: Thanks @R.G ,it helped me,Can you suggest if we can pass any argument from controller to ControllerAdvice class

Comment: A model attribute can be used to share the data if I am not wrong . [Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-modelattrib-methods) . This could also work : https://stackoverflow.com/a/52523250/4214241

Answer (score 0):

Your aspect code is quite chaotic and does not make much sense:

1. You are trying to check for a response before calling `proceed()`, as R.G said. Use something like `EmployeeResponse response = (EmployeeResponse) proceed()` instead, inspect the response and then decide what to do next.
2. You already bind the method parameters to `name` and `empId`, there is no need to use `pjp.getArgs()`.
3. `return arguments` does not make sense because you ought to return an `EmployeeResponse` object (either the original result or another one), not the array of method arguments.